# Do I need pata_atiixp or ata_generic kernel modules on a SATA only system?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, sata, pata

I don't have any IDE drives and my only SATA hard drive is running in AHCI mode, but my initrd image loads the pata_atiixp module. Is it safe to disable this module? And what about the ata_generic one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the first question: Yes

But anyway, it should be easy to generate a backup entry in your boot manager (with the original initrd and working kernel), in case something goes wrong.

To answer the second one - you can use

```
$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
...
```

On your running systems to see, if ata_generic is loaded and if it is, which modules depend on it (look at the *used by* column.

Comment: In addition to `lsmod`, if a module is loaded, you can try `rmmod pata_atiixp`. If the module is loaded and is used for anything, you won't be able to unload it.

Comment: Interesting, ata_generic is not being used by anything apparently. It does use libata, as does ahci, so it seems to be safe to not load both pata_atiixp and ata_generic in my case.

Comment: [It's mainly used to access devices setup by the BIOS](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ata_generic), and only for [specific classes](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/ata/ata_generic.c#L212). It can be useful if nobody has written a more specific driver - but they almost certainly have.